# etale cohomology and algebric K theory for algebraic stack

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over a perfect field $k$. Fix a prime $p$ which is invertible in $k$.
Thomason proved that there is Atiyah-Hirzebruch type spectral sequence that computes $K(1)$-local $K$ theory:
$$
E_2^{m,n}=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
H_{\acute{e}t}^m(X,\mathbb{Z}_p(i)) & n=2i  \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \Longrightarrow \pi_{n-m}L_{K(1)}K(X)
$$

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a smooth Artin (or DM stack) over $k$. Is there  Atiyah-Hirzebruch type spectral sequence that computes $K(1)$-local $K$ theory of stable $\infty$-category of perfect complexes on $\mathcal{X}$
$$
E_2^{m,n}=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
H_{\acute{e} t}^m(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{Z}_p(i)) & n=2i  \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \Longrightarrow \pi_{n-m}L_{K(1)}K(\text{perf}(\mathcal{X}))?
$$